# How to iterate through a list to find values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to iterate through a list of timestamps from SQLite3 (`sql_min`) to find matching values in a Pandas column (`df['Timestamp']`) and then return the corresponding row number (`df['date_index']`)

```
for item in sql_min:
    index = df.loc[df['Timestamp'] == item, 'date_index']
    print(index)
```

I hoping to return an integer of the row number but get
`Series([], Name: date_index, dtype: int32)` or 
`ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

Answer (score 1):

If you consider Timestamp as string you can try the following:

```
for item in sql_min:
    indx = df.date_index[df.index[df.timestamp.str.contains(item)]]
    print(indx.to_string(index=True))
```